# Error al tratar de autenticar con facebook , no reconoce acción facebook del controlador

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'

  devise_for :users,
             path: '',
             path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', edit:    'profile', sign_up: 'registration'},
             contollers: {:omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}
```

end

---

### Controlador: omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController <   Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

```
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will     throw if @user is not activated
       set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
   end
 end

 def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

end

---

### Modelo : User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = User.where(email: auth.info.email).first

    if user
      return user
    else
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.fullname = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.provider = auth.provider

        # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails,
        # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
        user.skip_confirmation!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un typo en tu archivo de rutas, pusiste `contollers` en vez de `controllers`, entonces debería ser:

```
devise_for :users,
             path: '',
             path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', edit:    'profile', sign_up: 'registration'},
             controllers: {:omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}
```

Comment: Esa era el error, ya quedo funcional con su orientación y configurando u parametrp que faltaba en facebook, routes s modifio y quedo funcionando dejandolo así: controllers: {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks'}